# vuex: Module not found

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I am beginner vue. I use vue cli. Here is my code.

App.vue:

```
<template>
  <div id="App">
    <Count/>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
  import Count from './components/Count';
  export default {
    name:'App',
    components:{
      Count
    }
  };
</script>
```

Count.vue:

```
<template>
  <div id="App">
    <button @click="increase">{{count}}</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import {store} from './store/store.js';

  export default {
    name:'App',
    computed:{
      count(){
        return store.state.count;
      }
    },
    methods:{
      increase(){
        store.state.count++;
      }
    }
  };
</script>
```

main.js:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'

Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

When I run serve, It compiled fail, say **Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './store/store.js'**.

I need someone to help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorry. I find the error,It was due to my carelessness.I import component with error path.